# Is there a way to disable android device programmatically?

Tags: android

I have an android tablet installed on a robot, which has separate accumulator, and I need to power off tablet when that accumulator is discharged.
Is there any way to do it from android application?
I can root the device if needed.

UPD - tablet - Acer Iconia A100, ICS.

UPD2

here is working code

```
try {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
           .command("/system/bin/su")
           .start();
            OutputStream o =process.getOutputStream();
            o.write("/system/bin/reboot -p\n".getBytes());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by disable?

Comment: You might be able to do this with Tasker, which may be easier, but would also mean you can do it programmaticaly.

Comment: Did you try `reboot -p`? I was told it works on Android-x86. (I don't have a device handy to check myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like that (That would work only on rooted devices):

```
try {
    // it's possible you'd have to provide full path to rebot here (ex. '/system/bin/reboot -p' ??)
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot -p"); 
} catch( Exception e ) { // pokemon catching

}
```

Full working example (update):

```
try {
    // if that's not working use '/system/bin/su' instead
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot -p"}); 

} catch( Exception e ) { }
```

Comment: Yes, reboot has worked! I didn't know that -p attribute will shutdown device(

Comment: I tested reboot in terminal emulator and all was Ok, but if I call Runtime.exec("reboot -p") it just hangs created process... Runtime.exec("su") works fine.

Comment: Yeah, because you have to call su first. I've updatated my answer with complete solution :) It works, I just checked it, you'll have to grant application su permission and remember them on each device so the process could be fully automated :)